# mcollective facts ohai for chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, puppet, mcollective

We have `chef` running in our Datacenter and recently we introduce `Mcollective` but when i am trying to work on `facts` i didn't find any good documents about `ohai` integration with `mco`

I found following Plugin:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/mcollective-ohai-facts

I installed as per documentation and restart mcollective server daemon and i got following error:

```
    [root@server1 root]# /etc/init.d/mcollective restart
    Shutting down mcollective:
Starting mcollective: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohai-7.6.0.rc.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:188: warning: character class has `[' without escape
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohai-7.6.0.rc.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:188: warning: regexp has `]' without escape
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.0.0.rc.0/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb:294: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting tAMPER (SyntaxError)
..._of?(Array) ? exec(*command, :close_others=>true) : exec(com...
                              ^
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.0.0.rc.0/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb:35
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohai-7.6.0.rc.0/lib/ohai/mixin/command.rb:26
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohai-7.6.0.rc.0/lib/ohai/dsl/plugin.rb:22
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohai-7.6.0.rc.0/lib/ohai/dsl.rb:20
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohai-7.6.0.rc.0/lib/ohai/loader.rb:21
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohai-7.6.0.rc.0/lib/ohai/system.rb:19
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ohai-7.6.0.rc.0/lib/ohai.rb:21
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /usr/libexec/mcollective/mcollective/facts/opscodeohai_facts.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/mcollective/pluginmanager.rb:169:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/mcollective/pluginmanager.rb:169:in `loadclass'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/mcollective/config.rb:156:in `loadconfig'
        from /usr/sbin/mcollectived:45
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I have following `gem` installed:

```
[root@server1 root]# /usr/bin/gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.6)
actionpack (4.1.6)
actionview (4.1.6)
activemodel (4.1.6)
activerecord (4.1.6)
activesupport (4.1.6)
addressable (2.3.6)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
berkshelf (3.2.1)
berkshelf-api-client (1.2.0)
buff-config (1.0.1)
buff-extensions (1.0.0)
buff-ignore (1.1.1)
buff-ruby_engine (0.1.0)
buff-shell_out (0.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.7.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
celluloid (0.16.0)
celluloid-io (0.16.1)
chef (12.0.0.alpha.2)
chef-zero (3.1.3)
cleanroom (1.0.0)
coderay (1.1.0)
dep-selector-libgecode (1.0.2)
dep_selector (1.0.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
faraday (0.9.0)
ffi (1.9.4)
ffi-yajl (1.1.0)
gem-wrappers (1.2.5)
hashie (2.1.2)
highline (1.6.21)
hike (1.2.3)
hitimes (1.2.2)
i18n (0.7.0.beta1)
ipaddress (0.8.0)
knife-vsphere (0.9.9)
libyajl2 (1.0.1)
mail (2.6.1)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (2.3, 1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.6.0)
minitar (0.5.4)
minitest (5.4.1)
mixlib-authentication (1.3.0)
mixlib-cli (1.5.0)
mixlib-config (2.1.0)
mixlib-log (1.6.0)
mixlib-shellout (2.0.0.rc.0)
multi_json (1.10.1)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
net-dhcp (1.2.1)
net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
net-ssh (2.9.1)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
net-ssh-multi (1.2.0)
netaddr (1.5.0)
nio4r (1.0.1)
nokogiri (1.6.3.1)
octokit (3.5.2)
ohai (7.6.0.rc.0)
plist (3.1.0)
pry (0.10.1)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.1.6)
railties (4.1.6)
rbvmomi (1.5.1)
retryable (1.3.6)
ridley (4.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sawyer (0.5.5)
semverse (1.2.1)
slop (3.6.0)
solve (1.2.1)
sprockets (2.12.2)
sprockets-rails (2.1.4)
stomp (1.3.4)
systemu (2.6.4)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (1.4.1)
timers (4.0.1)
trollop (2.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
uuidtools (2.1.5)
varia_model (0.4.0)
wmi-lite (1.0.0)
```

## Edit

I have both version of `ruby` 1.8 and 2.1

```
[root@server1]# /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-linux]
```

and

```
[root@server1]# /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Are you tied to mcollective? Chef 12 has a push jobs feature that offers similar capabilities. It's also worth noting that Ruby issues, in the chef world, are now largely solved by the omnibus installers which delivery an embedded instance of Ruby. I'm not a fan of rvm on production, but I understand why it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohai, and most Chef-related code in general, is no longer compatible with Ruby 1.8. Ohai 7.x will still run on Ruby 1.9.3, but late versions require 2.0+.

Comment: The traceback shows `/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/` all over. Methinks your Ruby install is busted.

Comment: I have rename `/usr/bin/ruby` and symlink with `ruby-2.1` now i am getting this error `from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'`

Comment: That isn't how you use RVM. Please fix your Ruby install and try all this again.

Comment: as you said i have build new `VM` to test and install `mcollective` using `yum` it install by default `1.8.x` ruby version because dependencies of rpm. Later i installed `2.1.x` ruby using `RVM` and set it default ruby version. Now how i tell mcollective to use ruby `2.1.x` version? Now i am getting this error `Starting mcollective: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/ext/parser.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
` look like it still looking into `1.8.7` how do i tell mcollective to use new ruby

Comment: You have to install mcollective by hand, not via RPM.

Comment: Great! finally it works! i installed `mcollective`  using tarball. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can hard code the ruby binary path on below binary `/usr/sbin/mcollectived`. Also if you installed mcollective with ruby1.8.7 then you need to copy the collective files to whatever ruby latest version path. 

`cp -rp /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/mcollective* /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/`

Comment: Additionally you need to make sure the respective gems should be installed for respective version of ruby. Just check if you current gem path looks for ruby 1.8.7, if so then you need to export GEM_PATH with latest version of ruby gem path whatever you have installed and install the necessary gems.